# How to distinguish field that requires null=True when blank=True is set in Django models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Some model fields such as DateTimeField require null=True option when blank=True option is set.

I'd like to know which fields require that (maybe dependent on backend DBMS), and there is any way to do this automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/28/django-tips-difference-between-blank-and-null/) should help to understand the difference on `blank` and `null` in Django

Comment: Thanks for introducing that post. Well, I already knew the difference, but I think it is more natural to have automatic null=True for non-string columns with blank=True without default value.

Answer (score 2):

null=True is used to tell that in DB value can be NULL
blank=True is only for django , so django doesn't raise error if field is blank e.g. in admin interface
so blank=True has nothing to do with DB
NULL requirement will vary from DB to DB, and it is upto you to decide if you want some column NULL or not