# Django REST Empty Fields

Tags: django, rest

Is there a way to allow for empty fields within the Django REST serilaizer for Boolean and Int fields.

```
class InputAttributes(serializers.Serializer):
    make = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
    speed = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    color = serializers.CharField(required=False,allow_blank=True)
```

I can use the allow_blank for CharFields but not for the others.
Based on the above I get,

```
A valid integer is required
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to distinguish field that requires null=True when blank=True is set in Django models?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005187/how-to-distinguish-field-that-requires-null-true-when-blank-true-is-set-in-djang)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"[Django REST Framework serializer field required=false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780731/django-rest-framework-serializer-field-required-false)" might help you.

Source: "[BooleanField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#booleanfield)"

> BooleanField
>
> A boolean representation.
>
> When using HTML encoded form input be aware that omitting a value will always be treated as setting a field to `False`, even if it has a `default=True` option specified. This is because HTML checkbox inputs represent the unchecked state by omitting the value, so REST framework treats omission as if it is an empty checkbox input.
>
> Corresponds to `django.db.models.fields.BooleanField`.
>
> Signature: `BooleanField()`
>
> [NullBooleanField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#nullbooleanfield)
>
> A boolean representation that also accepts `None` as a valid value.
>
> Signature: `NullBooleanField()`
>
> Corresponds to `django.db.models.fields.NullBooleanField`.

Comment: this may explain more as well. https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/commit/28ff6fb1ec02b7a04c4a0db54885f3735b6dd43f

Answer (score 1):

If you're finding this question because you actually want your BooleanField to send/receive `null` as a valid value because you've defined

```
null=True, default=None
```

in your model's `BooleanField`, then define the field in your serializer like this:

```
myBoolField = serializers.BooleanField(allow_null=True, default=None)
```

I thought that was what `NullBooleanField` did at first but it doesn't, I don't see what it's supposed to do really.

Answer (score -6):

```
color = serializers.CharField(null=True,Blank=True)
```

Comment: Please read "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)". Formatting is important on SO; Help is available to show how to use it when editing your text. "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)" will help too. Also, please explain why this should be the selected solution, and how it works; The goal is to educate, not just toss out code.